# Quotient Group question ambiguity about group order

Tags: group-theory

$\mathbb{R}$  and $\mathbb{Z} $ are groups under addition.

Show $a+\mathbb{Z} \in \mathbb{R/Z}$ is of finite order if and only if $a$ is rational.

How can this be of finite order for any $a$? Let $a=\frac{1}{2}$

Then the group coset $a+\mathbb{Z}$ is $\{...-\frac{5}{2},-\frac{3}{2},-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2},\frac{5}{2}...\}$

This is certainly not of finite order.

I'm obviously misunderstanding something- can someone help?

Comment: As an element of $R/Z$, it has order 2.

Comment: You are mixing up the concepts of the cardinality (~order) of the coset itself with the order of the coset *as a group element*  in the quotient group.

Comment: @NickyHekster Yes- thanks I realised this- if you look at my comments below I am still a bit stuck with this new understanding of the problem. I reckon now I might have a guess as to why I am confused. If we have an element $g$ from a ordinary group- (not a quotient group). Then $g^2 $and $g^3$ are $g*g$ and $g*g*g$ respectively. I think I am confusing the binary operation also. When we thing about the order of a coset $gH$ : $(gH)^2 $ is $(g^2)H$ and so $((g*g)H)$ ...

Comment: @NickyHekster So when we find order of $(a+\mathbb{Z})$ , $(a+\mathbb{Z})^2$ is not as I am confusing it to be $2(a+\mathbb{Z}) $but instead $(a+a)+\mathbb{Z}$ =$(2a)+\mathbb{Z}$. SO in fact when finding the order of $\frac{p}{q} + \mathbb{Z} $ ,  $(\frac{p}{q} + \mathbb{Z})^q $ is not $q(\frac{p}{q} + \mathbb{Z}) $ but actually $q*\frac{p}{q} + \mathbb{Z}$ $=p+\mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z}$. Is this right?

Comment: First of all, the binary operation of the group is inherited by the quotient group, but then applied to the "multiplication" of cosets. Your second confusion: you should make a difference between a *multiplicative* and *additive* notation of the binary group operation. In multiplicative format $g^k$ Is similar to the additive $g + \dots + g$ ($k$ times).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An element of an additive group has finite order if there is a non null $n$ integer such that $n(a+ Z)= Z$.

In the case of $1/2$, we have that $2(1/2 + Z)=(1+Z)=Z$. Therefore the order of $1/2$ if finite.

Comment: Why are you using Algebra with sets- is this legal? Also if you have $2(\frac{1}{2} + \mathbb{Z})$ that becomes $(1+2\mathbb{Z})$ which isnt $\mathbb{Z}$ right?

Comment: With Quotient groups the idenity coset is the the group that your quotienting by right?

Comment: Here $R/Z$ is the quotient set for the equivalence relation $x\sim y$ if and only if $x-y\in Z$. The quotient set is the set of all equivalence classes. And a equivalence class is a set. For instance,  the class of $1/2$ is $1/2 +Z$

Comment: $2(1/2 + Z)=1+Z$, by definition. I mean, the operations does not depends on the representant chosen.

Comment: But I see why this is confusing.The point is that  ${\mathbb Z}+{\mathbb Z}$ is equal to ${\mathbb Z}$, not $2{\mathbb Z}$.

Comment: The operations is not undenstood as a set operation, but it is undenstood  as an operation of equivalence classes. Watch out!

Comment: @Derek Holt But why? And I dont see how in this case . When multiplying the set in my question by $2$  you get $\{...-5,-3,-1,1,3,5...\}$ This is not the whole of $\mathbb{Z}$ This is only the odd numbers.

Comment: @zap "the operations..." Could you elaborate on this please- I don't understand.

Comment: Because if we proceed like that, the operation is not well definded, because $1+2\cdot Z$ is not a equivence class of any thing, it is not an element of $R/Z$. You must review how is defined the sum in a quotient group.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_group

Comment: @Arcane1729 $\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}=\{a+b : a,b \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ so by taking $a=0$,  we see that this is just the whole of the integers again, and in principle this is all we are doing to the cosets

Comment: $R/Z$ as a aditive group needs a sum, in this case the sum is defined by $(a + Z) + (b + Z):= a+b + Z$. It is standard way to define it. Further, we understand $2(a+ Z)=(a+Z)+(a+Z):=(a+a + Z)$.

Comment: One thing is how you define sum as sum of sets, another thing is the suitable sum which endows the set with structure of group.

Comment: @zap please read my comment under the original question to NickyHekster. What do you think?

Comment: @zap Yes I think understand- thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

By taking the quotient, we are effectively treating any integer as the identity element. Hence an element in $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ has finite order if some multiple of the coset representative is an integer.But this is precisely the definition of a rational number.

Comment: Suppose $\frac{p}{q}$ is in it's lowest terms. $q \neq 1$. If you have $(\frac{p}{q}+\mathbb{Z})$ If you multiply by $q$  the smallest number you can multiply to get an integer set, you get $p+q\mathbb{Z}$. This is not identical to $\mathbb{Z}$ though?? Some elements from  $\mathbb{Z}$ are missing

Comment: Since the quotient is a group, $p(\frac{p}{q} + \mathbb{Z})$ must be an element as well, which $p+q\mathbb{Z}$ certainly isn't.

Comment: @please read my comment under the original question to NickyHekster. What do you think? –

Comment: I have got it- +1